# Уведомления по раписанию с базы данных

Tags: java, android, уведомления

У меня есть вопрос: есть в базе данных таблица с расписанием, мне нужно отправлять пуш уведомдления за 5 минут (или другое время) до времени в расписании. я не знаю, как это сделать. Уведомления должны приходить даже при выключенном приложении.